# How I can take the coordinates of a block of numbers?

Tags: perl

I have a problem tha bothers me a lot...
I have a file with two columns (thanks to your help in a previous question) like:

```
14430001        0.040
14430002        0.000
14430003        0.990
14430004        1.000
14430005        0.050
14430006        0.490
....................
```

the first column is coordinates the second probabilities.
I am trying to find the blocks with probability >=0.990 and to be more than 100 in size.
As output I want to be like this:

```
14430001        14430250
14431100        14431328
18750003        18750345
.......................
```

where the first column has the coordinate of the start of each block and the second the end of it.

I wrote this script:

```
use strict;
#use warnings;
use POSIX;

my $scores_file = $ARGV[0];

#finds the highly conserved subsequences


open my $scores_info, $scores_file or die "Could not open $scores_file: $!";
#open(my $fh, '>', $coords_file) or die;
my $count = 0;
my $cons = "";
my $newcons = "";
while( my $sline = <$scores_info>)  {
      my @data = split('\t', $sline);
      my $coord = $data[0];
      my $prob = $data[1];
     if ($data[1] >= 0.990) {
      #$cons = "$cons + '\n' + $sline + '\n'";
    $cons = join("\n", $cons, $sline);
    # print $cons;
     $count++;
    if($count >= 100) {

    $newcons = join("\n", $newcons, $cons);
    my @array = split /'\n'/, $newcons;
    print @array;
            }
}
 else {
   $cons = "";
   $count = 0;
   }
```

}

It gives me the lines with probability >=0.990 (the first if works) but the coordinates are wrong. When Im trying to print it in a file it stacks, so I have only one sample to check it.
Im terrible sorry if my explanations aren't helpful, but I am new in programming.

Please, I need your help...
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: "something is wrong" is quite vague !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using too much variables. Also, after splitting the array and assigning its parts to variables, use the new variables rather than the original array.

```
sub output {
    my ($from, $to) = @_;
    print "$from\t$to\n";
}

my $threshold = 0.980;   # Or is it 0.990?
my $count = 0;
my ($start, $last);
while (my $sline = <$scores_info>) {
    my ($coord, $prob) = split /\t/, $sline;
    if ($prob >= $threshold) {
        $count++;
        defined $start or $start = $coord;
        $last = $coord;
    } else {
        output($start, $last) if $count > 100;
        undef $start;
        $count = 0;
    }
}
output($start, $last) if $count > 100;
```

(untested)

Comment: Almost there - repeat the `if ($count > 100) { ... }` block after the while loop, in case we end with a block-in-progress.